# Distance measurement logic

Tags: javascript, html, math, distance, trigonometry

Boy it was hard to give this problem a name...

I've been working on this "progress bar" logic, that when ever the user moves 
his/her mouse - the indicator (in this case its progress bar) shows how close cursor is to the wanted object.

**Basically** it's like "hot 'n cold" kind of thing.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb85yfrw/)

...and this is the problem part

```
relativeDistance = ((maxMouseDistance - distance) / maxDistance);

        if ((maxMouseDistance - distance) > maxDistance){
             relativeDistance = 1- (((maxMouseDistance) / maxDistance) -1);
        }
```

Since my code and distance measurements are based on trigonometry, it has a small problem: There's actually atleast two points on the screen, where the wanted distances are equal.

**Try it and you'll notice what I mean.**

Any ideas on how I could get rid of that...It's propably because of the logics, but I just don't see it.

Comment: ... there is a name for all the points on a plane that have the same distance from a point. it's called a circle. Other than that: that is wrong with having points that are equally far from the point you?re interested in?

Comment: why don't you simply take the coordinates of the center of your target and calculate the distance between mouse pointer and the center. Then you could express this distance in percents.

Comment: Thanks for both of the comments. @Burki, my whole point is to get that bar filled only when the cursor is on that sertain target element. How would you suggest me to use circle to measure percentual distance from cursor to target?

Comment: @rashmatash, how do I express that distance in percents? If the distance is, lets say 245, how do I put/divide that in such way that it would give me a result to use with that progress bar?

Comment: You could take the farthest distance the mouse pointer could get from the target (usually one of the 4 corners of the screen) and treat that as 100%. So, for example, if the farthest point from your target is 1500 pixels and the mouse distance is 245 then you can calculate the progress bar to be `100*(245/1500)` which is 16%.

Comment: @rashmatash, thank you very much! I had that vice versa all the time, like this `(maxDistance/distanceOfMouseToTarget)*100`. Now I only had to turn it around like this `relativeDistance = 1.00-( distanceOfMouseToTarget/maxDistance);` and works like a charm!

Comment: Great!..................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffj6wrg6/) do what you want?

It uses the nearest corner to the mouse rather than the farthest corner. It will show 0% when the mouse is in any corner, and a positive percentage as the mouse approaches the target, even if the target is off-centre.

```
(function () {

    var mX
    , mY
    , distance
    , $distance = $('#distance')
    , $element = $('#thetarget')
    , maxMouseDistance
    , relativeDistance;
    var theWidth = $(document).width();
    var theHeight = $(document).height();

    $("#theWidth").text(theWidth);
    $("#theHeight").text(theHeight);

    function pythagoras(length, height) {        
        var length2 = length * length
          , height2 = height * height
        return Math.sqrt((length2 + height2));
    }


    /**/
    var target = $("#thetarget");
    target.css({
      cursor: "default"
    , border: "1px solid black"
    , margin: 0});
    var position = target.position(); // top left of target element
    var tX = Math.floor(position.left)
    var tY = Math.floor(position.top)
    $("#targetPosition").text(tX + ":" + tY);

    var corners = [
      [0, 0]
    , [theWidth, 0]
    , [theWidth, theHeight]
    , [0, theHeight]
    ]

   function distanceToNearestCorner(x, y) {
     var cornerX = x < tX ? 0 : theWidth
     var cornerY = y < tY ? 0 : theHeight
   
     return pythagoras(cornerX - tX, cornerY - tY)
   }

    /*Mouse movement tracking*/
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        /*Get mouse coordinates*/
        mX = e.pageX;
        mY = e.pageY;
    
        /*calculate distance between mouse and element*/
        distance = pythagoras(tX - mX, tY - mY);
        maxMouseDistance  = distanceToNearestCorner(mX, mY)
        relativeDistance = ((maxMouseDistance - distance) / maxMouseDistance);    

        $distance.text(distance);

        var decimals = distance / 100;
        var percents = 100 - (distance / 100);
        $("#mouse").text(mX + ":" + mY);
        //$("#distanceDecimals").text(decimals);
        //$("#dFarCorner").text(maxDistance);
        $("#md2FarCorner").text(maxMouseDistance);
        $("#formula").text("(E to C max / M to C max) / (M to E distance/100)");
        $("#theNumber").text(relativeDistance);
        $('.fill').width((relativeDistance * 100) + "%");
    });

})();
```

It doesn't update all the fields, but it does update the progress bar.

---

**Original answer**

You seem to have plenty of functions in there which are not being called.

Here's one that I have rewritten... but it doesn't get called:

```
function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
  var deltaX = elem.offset().left - mouseX;
  var deltaY = elem.offset().top - mouseY;
  var delta2 = deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY;
  var delta = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(delta2))
  return delta
}

var elem = document.getElementById("targetPosition")
var relativeDistance = calculateDistance(elem , mX, mY)
```

In my implementation, `elem` is the HTML element that you consider to be the target. My function is an application of Pythagoras' theorem: it returns the square root of the sum of the distance from the target along the x and y axes, giving the length of the shortest line between the mouse and the target.

When I insert this into your jsFiddle, I see 0 appearing in the M2E Distance field when my cursor is just above the "T" of "Target".

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've actually got that Pythagoras' A^2*B^2=C^2 clause there by the name of _calculateDistanceToCorners_ and its being called out when I'm setting the farthest corner. I can get the distance between cursor and target out just fine, but if I want to get the percentual result, I have to compare it to something. Thats why I must - according to my sense - compare that distance to distance of something else, which in this case could/should be the farthest point from the element. So either my question is unclear or I understood you wrong.

Comment: With your implementation, when Target Position and Mouse Position are shown as the same, then M2E Distance is a positive number (e.g. 45)... Let me get back to you with a complete solution.

Comment: I've just made a correction to `distanceToNearestCorner()`. You should use the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is correct. It's called a locus. http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/locirev1.shtml

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I must admit that it was - as your nick - a riddle to me.